# Checking/unchecking a checkbox without selecting its parent element?

Tags: jquery

I've got a simple webpage set up that has an unordered list with 3 list items in it. Inside each list item is a checkbox with some text right next to it. I have it set up so that when a list item is clicked, it highlights that particular list item (via jQuery's 'addClass' and 'removeClass' methods. That all works fine.

What I would like to do, though, is be able to check or uncheck a checkbox *without* it selecting that checkbox's parent element. In other words, if list item 1 is currently highlighted, and I then click list item 3's *checkbox*, then list item 1 should remain highlighted. I've tried several different things so far, but to no avail.

Here's the jsFiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/DXdR6/

And here's the code...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<style>
.selected {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.unselected {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
    width: 100px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("li").mousedown(function(){
        $("li").removeClass("unselected");
        $("li").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

  <ul>
    <li class="unselected" ><input type="checkbox">Item 1</li>
    <li class="unselected" ><input type="checkbox">Item 2</li>
    <li class="unselected" ><input type="checkbox">Item 3</li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the event functions parameter like this `e.target` and filter the action if the target is a checkbox. [Updated fiddle here (click).](http://jsfiddle.net/DXdR6/1/)

```
$("li").mousedown(function(e){
  if (e.target.nodeName !== 'INPUT') {
    $("li").removeClass("unselected");
    $("li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  }
});
```

You could also use `$(e.target).attr('type') === 'checkbox'` for example. I think there's several other way of getting the input type, also.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(function() {

    $("input").change(function(){

        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(this).parent().removeClass().addClass("selected");   
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().removeClass().addClass("unselected");
        }

   });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DXdR6/2/)

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but thanks anyways. The solution by m59 worked perfectly.